# is used to live vs is used to living here

Tags: tense

> 1. He is used to live here.

vs

> 2. He is used to living here.

and

> 3. He is used to drive a Mercedes.

vs

> 4. He is used to driving a Mercedes.

What is the difference between sentence 1 and 2, and 3 and 4? When should one use the verb in the infinitive and when to use the verb with '-ing'?

---

Some examples from Google:

> 1. He is used to live by himself.
> 2. He is used to live in a family.
> 3. He is used to drive fast.
> 4. He is used to drive complex projects.

I am wondering why '-ing' is not used in the examples above. Are they grammatical mistakes?

Comment: Recommended reading: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/used-to_1 Try to understand the difference between... *"He **is** used to..."* and *"He used to..."*

Comment: @MaulikV - thanks for the comment. I do clearly understand the difference between the two. My confusion is not what's the difference, but only with "is used to live or living" - i think i have come across few examples where 'is used to live or drive" has been used. So I am wondering why sometimes these sentence structures like the ones I provided in my edited question are used.

Comment: Can you provide links to the googled examples 1-3 (4 is OK). They don't make sense to me as is but perhaps some context would help.

Comment: @user3169 - please see this link https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he+is+used+to+live%22&biw=1024&bih=639&noj=1&ei=oY_hVLaxGY7JuASh9oLADA&start=0&sa=N - even such sentence constructions don't make sense to me. But it is hard to believe so many people would make grammatical mistakes. Thanks

Comment: By locale many seem to be BrE or European sources. I can only speak from AmE point of view. Or poor grammar, I can't say.

Comment: First page of that Google link comprises questions on the usage & bad grammar. Wasn't worth looking at page 2. Better source for confirmation would be [NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+is+used+to+live%2CHe+is+used+to+living&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHe%20is%20used%20to%20living%3B%2Cc0) which gives no instances of 'he is used to live'

Comment: You can find similar grammar if you Google "He is use to live"

Answer (score 3):

> 2) He is used to living here.
>   4) He is used to driving a Mercedes.

are OK. "used to" here means "accustomed".

Regarding the used+infinitive verb form, I think you mean something like (in you **Edited** questions)

> 3) A sports car is used to drive fast?

is OK, but it does not make logical sense with "He".

> 4) He is used to drive complex projects.

means something like it was his job, and is OK as written.

> 1) He is used to live by himself.
>   2) He is used to live in a family.

don't make sense though.

Answer (score 2):

> 2. He is used to living here.

and

> 4. He is used to driving a Mercedes.

is correct.
Both of these sentences mean that he is accustomed to performing a certain task.

> 1. He is used to live here.

and

> 3. He is used to drive a Mercedes.

are grammatically incorrect.
I'm guessing they meant:

> 1. He used to live here.

and

> 3. He used to drive a Mercedes.

Those two sentences would mean that he no longer performs a certain task.

Comment: could you please go through the edited question and edit your answer accordingly ? Thanks