# When to use speak or speaking

Tags: verbs, gerunds

I have a habit of saying "I am quite used to speak English"

I know it should be "speaking".

Can someone explain why in simple terms. I'm trying to understand but I'm still confused

Comment: You're probably confusing "I used to speak" with "I'm used to speaking", which are entirely unrelated structures.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is used to live vs is used to living here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49842/is-used-to-live-vs-is-used-to-living-here)

Answer (score 1):

The whole of the answer is that the adjectival phrase *used to* ('in the habit of', 'accustomed to') requires an *-ing* clause. This is no more logical or predictable than that the word *used* has an /s/ in it: it is simply a fact about that word that has to be learnt along with other properties.

You may be confusing it with the **verb** *used* (nearly always in the simple past), which does take a "*to* infinitive clause". This is also different from the transitive verb *use* (with the sound /z/ rather than /s/) which means "make use of".

So in

> I am quite used to speaking English. ("I am familiar with speaking English").

the *am* tells you that *used to* is adjectival here.

Whereas in

> I used to speak English. ("I spoke English regularly or habitually")

*used* (/jusd/) is a verb,

and in

> I used English ("I made use of English")

*used* (/juzd/) is a different verb.